# Descargar un archivo excel, pdf o cvs de forma local

Tags: angular, typescript

mi pregunta es como hacer para descargar un archivo Excel, PDF, etc desde una función en angular?, lo que requiero es poder al dar clic en un botón descargar un archivo desde una carpeta de mi proyecto y realizar la descarga.

En HTML sé que era con href en etiqueta , pero en angular no sé cómo, lo que he investigado es para generar desde cero ya sea por medio de API, pero no lo que requiero.

Si alguien sabe me podría ayudar por favor.

Comment: en mis proyectos angular yo utilizo esto: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por comentar, por lo que veo es para generar uno desde cero no?, el detalle es que yo ya tengo el excel, solo por temas de ahora lo que requiero es simular la descarga de ese archivo,

Answer (score 0):

```js
const type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
const base64 = ... // archivo a descargar;

fetch(`data:${type};base64,${base64}`)
  .then((res) => res.blob())
  .then((file) => {
    const a: any = document.getElementById('globalLink');
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'nombrearchivo';
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.click();
```